# Assigning Type of list with PropertyInfo.PropertyType giving type not found

Tags: c#, .net

I apologize if this is a dumb question, I'm just getting started with this stuff, but I'm having a little trouble with assigning a type of list via a Type variable. The method is supposed to create and assign properties to an object. I'm getting a "The type or namespace 'propType' could not be found" error in the `parseEnumList<propType>` spot. Could someone tell me why I can't set the list type to be the type of the property?

```
public T getFromForm<T>(){
    NameValueCollection form = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form;
    T t = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in typeof(T).GetProperties())
    {
        Type propType = prop.PropertyType;

        if (IsPropertyACollection(prop))
            prop.SetValue(t, parseEnumList<propType>(form.Get(prop.Name)), null);
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(form.Get(prop.Name)))
            prop.SetValue(t, Convert.ChangeType(form.Get(prop.Name),propType), null);
    }

    return t;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: here is the code for `parseEnumList`

```
public List<T> parseEnumList<T>(string list)
{
    List<string> stringList = list.Split(',').ToList<string>();

    List<T> enumList = stringList.ConvertAll(delegate(string x)
    {
        return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), x);
    });

    return enumList;
}
```

Comment: What is `parseEnumList`? (Now would be a good time to start following .NET naming conventions, btw...)

Comment: sorry, that's a dumb little helper I made. I'm adding that to the original post. Is there a good reference for .NET naming conventions? (I suppose I could Google that)

Comment: Yes, it's actually in the same file right now

Comment: Yes, you should Google that. You should *always* do some basic research before asking a question.

Comment: Basically, you're trying to use generics (compile-time type information) from execution-time type information. You can't do that terribly easily. This has been asked before - I'll see if I can find a duplicate...

Comment: I honestly did try to search for something similar without much luck. Its probably due to my lack of knowledge of the terminology

Comment: Searching for this is tricky, certainly - see the question I've closed this one as a duplicate of. Searching for .NET naming conventions isn't difficult though :)

Comment: ha, yeah, sorry about that. Got caught up in my typing and didn't think about it :)